# color washing off black mulch

Tags: landscaping, mulch

A gardener applied black mulch that he said is natural and not dyed.  Yet when it rains, the color attaches to my dog.  Is it normal for undyed mulch to have color wash off?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest that most mulch is a brown colour and your black mulch is dyed.

Comment: I concur, it is dyed.

Answer (score 2):

I work in the horticulture trade. All colored mulch—black, dark brown (chocolate), gold, red and (believe it or not) blue—is dyed. The only commonly available mulch that is **not** dyed is shredded bark and arborist wood chips.

Color leaches from wood mulch only if that mulch is dyed, so your landscaper is either misinformed or is mis-informing you. Theoretically, once the mulch thoroughly dries off it should stop leaching color, although I've known mulch to continue to leach onto concrete for several weeks.